# nodemailer - can't send mail with rediffmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to send mail from rediffmail using nodemailer
Here's the code snippet

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.rediffmail.com", // hostname
  port:25, secureConnection: false,
  secure: false,
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
  },
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAILADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.MAILPASS,
  },
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.MAILADDRESS,
    to: email,
    subject: "Sending using Node.js",
    html: "<h1>hoohaa</h1>That was eafefesy!",
  };



transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log(
                        `Password recovery Email sent to ${email} : ${info.response}`
                      );
                    }}
```

and the error which I get is :

> {          errno: -4039,   code: 'ESOCKET',           syscall:
> 'connect',        address: '202.137.235.17',   port: 25,   command:
> 'CONN' }

Answer (score 0):

Remove the TLS. You're not using ssl so you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use smtp.gmail.com ?

Comment: but i'm using rediffmail

Comment: Please use comment section to ask question about the post, please don't use answer section for questions.